# Visual Code IDE curly brace formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying some TypeScript stuff in Visual Studio Code Editor.
When the intelligence generates a class or function, the curly brace is opening in the same line. I don't prefer that style. I needed the curly brace to be started on the new line always. Can you tell me how to make that and which settings to be turned on?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not recommend this settings you can add the following entries to your `settings.json` to achieve that behavior:

```json
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true
```

Now every time you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format your code the braces will be set on a new line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, may I know why you mentioned that 'I do not recommend'?

Comment: Because there are some guidelines ([here is an example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)) many developers use. One basic of them is the brace formatting on the same line. It is easier to read and maintain code if it looks the same/similar. So somebody else, who is used to that guidelines, may struggle a little bit to get familiar with your code. That's why I do not recommend to change that rule without a specific cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot HaaLeo